# create contentDB in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, 2016

I am trying to create a content db from asp.net application c# hosted in share point server.

my code is

```
  SPWebApplication elevatedWebApp = spWeb.Site.WebApplication;
                        string serverName = "xxx\xxx";
                        string newDbName = "WSS_Content_1";
                        string username = "xxxx\\spfarm";
                        string password = "xxxxx";
                        var contentDatabase = elevatedWebApp.ContentDatabases.Add(serverName,newDbName,username,password,0,1,0);

                        contentDatabase.Update();
                        elevatedWebApp.Update();
```

I got this error message

**Cannot connect to database master at SQL server The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.**

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Is it event receiver? Or what type of application? Under which account it is running?

Comment: Use powershell to create web appln, content db etc  entities instead of C#. is there any particular reason for creating these entities using C#

Answer (score 0):

the issue is mostly with the account under which the application is running, If the application is running under non-farm account then you will get access denied.

account should need DB creator and Security admin on the SQL Server.